# Antivirus blocks writing to autorun registry

Tags: c#, .net, registry, antivirus

I have a .NET program where I need to add itself to autorun like so:

```
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubkey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
key.SetValue("Name", "Path");
```

However when the program tries to write to registry, anti-virus detects my program as a virus and deletes it, are there any ways of preventing this?

Comment: Set the antivirus to allow your program as an exception.

Comment: Just think about it for a moment. If it was so easy then antivirus programs will be useless. Advise your users to add your program to their antivirus exception list

Comment: You've got one shot at altering the user's machine configuration like that.  You get it when the user starts your installer and acknowledges the elevation prompt.  After that, no, you are doing something you shouldn't do so you get treated as a pest instead of a feature.